# Unresolved dependency: 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:3.1.5'

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa

Unresolved dependency: 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:3.1.5'

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.7.12
 

com.lcwd.user.service
UserService
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
UserService
This is user service

<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.7</spring-cloud.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.project-lombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```